# PHP - Abstract class that also abstracts methods. Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: php

Assume I have this interface...

```
interface Foo {
    public function bar();
    public function nothing();
}
```

I'm tasked with writing an "abstract class that also abstracts the methods", and I just want to make sure that I'm writing this correctly. My code is as follows...

```
abstract class Bar implements Foo {
    abstract public function bar();
    abstract public function nothing();
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: reallly what do you want?

Comment: Abstract class in your example is completely redundant. If you extend that abstract class, interface already forces you to implement methods `bar` and `nothing`. You don't need to "double" enforce it by declaring methods abstract. What you should probably do is write an implementation of either one or both methods so that all child classes don't have to repeat the same job. This way, what's the point of that abstract class? It does nothing, you can just implement the interface directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement the interface in your abstract class. Your abstract class provides an interface like contract to classes that extend it.

```
abstract class Bar {
    abstract public function bar();
    abstract public function nothing();
    public function concreteMethod() {
        print "I can do this in an abstract class";
    }
}

class Concrete extends Bar {
    public function bar() {
       print "in bar";
    }
    public function nothing() {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is a somewhat unusual situation, but the fact remains that this is the task assigned to me...and am just looking to confirm that I've properly written it. A simple yes, or no with a correction would be wonderful. Thanks for your time, it's appreciated!

Comment: Without reading the assignment I can't say. But, it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't seem right, I'm all ears as to what the appropriate correction would be. I've googled to my hearts content, and I can't seem to find (as this is an unusual scenario) an example of an abstract class that also abstracts methods of an interface.

Comment: Ok, I don't know this for sure, because, like I said, I didn't read the assignment. But, I think what they are asking you to do is to write an abstract class that has both abstract and concrete methods. A class that extends that abstract class would then be forced to implement the methods declared abstract in the parent class, but not implement the concrete methods the parent provides. But, I don't really know what they are asking you for because your description of that is not very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any need to implement some shared (by all subclasses) functionality in the abstract class, you should better derive directly from the interface, to make things not unnecessarily complicated.

In this case, the whole thing could be sensefully simplyfied to:

```
<?php

    interface Foo 
    {
        public function bar();
        public function nothing();
    }

    class C implements Foo 
    {
        public function bar() {
            echo 'bar';
        }

        public function nothing() {
            echo 'nothing';
        }
    }

    $obj = new C();
    $obj->bar();

    ?>
```

Read more at:

> [Is it good or bad for an abstract class to implement an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27562249/3653989)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but one chance is that create abstract class with implements interface like this.

```
interface Foo {
    public function bar();
    public function nothing();
}


abstract class Bar implements Foo  {
    public function bazz() {
        echo ' Bye';  
    }  
}

class Test extends Bar {
    public function bar()
    {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
    public function nothing()
    {
        echo 'World';
    }
}
```

By this you have your abstract class having abstract methods from a interface. It also used in some architecture design where you want a parent class as abstract class but define all abstract methods in interface.